# List all .zip files that contain an error file (batch, cmd)

Tags: batch-file, findstr, errorlevel

I have a folder with a bunch of zip files, some of which contain an "*error.pdf" file. I need to make an "errors.txt" file containing the filenames of the zip files that contain such an error file.

I need help with the condition. FINDSTR sets ERRORLEVEL to 0 if the string is found, to 1 if it is not. I've tried `if not errorlevel 1` and `if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0`.

```
for %%X in (*) do (
    "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "%%X" | findstr error > nul
    if errorlevel 0(
        ECHO "%%X" >> errors.txt
    )
)
```

Right now nothing happens (if condition is always false), if I set the if condition to always be true it writes all filenames to errors.txt.

`"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "%%X" | findstr error` does output the filenames of the *error.pdfs

Comment: Use `findstr /IEC:"error.pdf"` since file names on Windows are case-insensitive and to match your search described criterion. Then put a _space_ between `if errorlevel 0` and `(`. You probably want to iterate over ZIP files only, so use `for %%X in (*.zip) do` (you may even use multiple masks like `*.zip *.rar` if needed). Finally, change echoing to `>>errors.txt echo(%%X` to avoid `""` and tralining _spaces_ to be output...

Comment: Have you considered refining your executable command options like this `l "%%X" -i!*error.pdf`

Comment: Um - but as `if errorlevel 0` means "if the errorlevel is 0 **or greater than zero** then you should use `if not errorlevel 1` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a missing space between `if errorlevel 0` and `(` (thanks to aschipfl).

The correct condition for the if statement was also `if not errorlevel 1` as mentioned by Magoo

This is the working code (with improvements mentioned by aschipfl)

```
for %%X in (*.zip) do (
    "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "%%X" | findstr error > nul
        if not errorlevel 1 (
        ECHO %%X >> errors.txt
        )
        )
```

Comment: You could simplify the command with [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) on success `&&` to a single line => `for %%X in (*.zip) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "%%~X"|findstr error >nul &&(ECHO %%X >> errors.txt)`

Comment: @LotPings thanks I'll note it for later, but I'm using multiple lines for better readability